# Incorrect output when using lodash on results returned by mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, lodash

I have a result set returned from a mongodb query and am using lodash to reformat it. I am trying to convert the array of objects into a single object. The problem is when I use lodash on the result set, I get unexpected output.

**NOTE:** Running the snippet on codepen/codesandbox gives correct output, but not when used directly from mongoose results.

**Mongoose Query**

```
try {
    const petInfo = await pets.find({ userId: user_id, petId: pet_id })
                              .select({
                                  "_id": 0,
                                  "createdAt": 0,
                                  "updatedAt": 0,
                                  "__v": 0
                              });

    if(!petInfo) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: "FAILED_TO_FETCH_PET_INFO" });
    }

    let newObj = _.reduce(petInfo, (acc, cur)=> { return _.assign(acc, cur) }, {});
    return res.status(200).json(newObj);
}
catch (error) {
    req.errorMsg = error.message; // Log actual error
    return res.status(500).json({ message: "SOME_ERROR_OCCURRED" });
}
```

**Result from mongoose find query (petInfo)**

```
[
    {
        "age": {
            "days": "",
            "months": "",
            "years": ""
        },
        "userId": "45422605180207851194",
        "name": "Oscar",
        "gender": "FEMALE",
        "type": "Dog",
        "breed": "",
        "weight": "",
        "spayOrNeuter": false,
        "petId": "KSVv7yJLnUWX3n"
    }
]
```

**Lodash snippet**

```
let newObj = _.reduce(petInfo, (acc, cur)=> { return _.assign(acc, cur) }, {});
return res.status(200).json(newObj);
```

**Result after modification**

```
{
    "$__": {
        "strictMode": true,
        "selected": {
            "_id": 0,
            "createdAt": 0,
            "updatedAt": 0,
            "__v": 0
        },
        "getters": {
            "age": {
                "days": "",
                "months": "",
                "years": ""
            }
        },
        "wasPopulated": false,
        "scope": {
            "age": {
                "days": "",
                "months": "",
                "years": ""
            },
            "userId": "45422605180207851194",
            "name": "Oscar",
            "gender": "FEMALE",
            "type": "Dog",
            "breed": "",
            "weight": "",
            "spayOrNeuter": false,
            "petId": "KSVv7yJLnUWX3n"
        },
        "activePaths": {
            "paths": {
                "userId": "init",
                "petId": "init",
                "name": "init",
                "gender": "init",
                "type": "init",
                "breed": "init",
                "age.days": "init",
                "age.months": "init",
                "age.years": "init",
                "weight": "init",
                "spayOrNeuter": "init"
            },
            "states": {
                "ignore": {},
                "default": {},
                "init": {
                    "userId": true,
                    "name": true,
                    "gender": true,
                    "type": true,
                    "breed": true,
                    "age.days": true,
                    "age.months": true,
                    "age.years": true,
                    "weight": true,
                    "spayOrNeuter": true,
                    "petId": true
                },
                "modify": {},
                "require": {}
            },
            "stateNames": [
                "require",
                "modify",
                "init",
                "default",
                "ignore"
            ]
        },
        "pathsToScopes": {},
        "cachedRequired": {},
        "session": null,
        "$setCalled": {},
        "emitter": {
            "_events": {},
            "_eventsCount": 0,
            "_maxListeners": 0
        },
        "$options": {
            "skipId": true,
            "isNew": false,
            "willInit": true
        },
        "nestedPath": "age"
    },
    "isNew": false,
    "_doc": {
        "age": {
            "days": "",
            "months": "",
            "years": ""
        },
        "userId": "45422605180207851194",
        "name": "Oscar",
        "gender": "FEMALE",
        "type": "Dog",
        "breed": "",
        "weight": "",
        "spayOrNeuter": false,
        "petId": "KSVv7yJLnUWX3n"
    },
    "$locals": {},
    "$init": true
}
```

Comment: can you show your mongoose query?

Comment: Sure. Hold on a minute.

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is because mongoose doesn't return the object you think it does. Instead, it returns a 'mongoose' object with a bunch of methods ect ect. There are 2 ways around this, either call [`.lean()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) on your query or [`toJSON()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#toJSON) on the result to sanitize result into normal js object.

**.lean()**

```
const petInfo = await pets.find({ userId: user_id, petId: pet_id })
    .select({
        "_id": 0,
        "createdAt": 0,
        "updatedAt": 0,
        "__v": 0
    }).lean();
```

**.toJSON()**

```
const petInfo = await pets.find({ userId: user_id, petId: pet_id })
    .select({
        "_id": 0,
        "createdAt": 0,
        "updatedAt": 0,
        "__v": 0
    }).lean();

const parsed = petInfo.toJSON()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query will return the result set as document objects instead of plain objects, which is why you get all the additional information like strictMode, getters, etc.

You could use the `lean()` function in order to get plain objects only (see https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html), e.g.:

```
const petInfo = await pets.find({ userId: user_id, petId: pet_id })
                                      .select({
                                          "_id": 0,
                                          "createdAt": 0,
                                          "updatedAt": 0,
                                          "__v": 0
                                      }).lean();
```